# Potential Android virus removal and best practices

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, malware

I was browsing the web and I ended up on a site with one of those pop ups that plagued my browser window with "Your device is infected, please go to insert dodgy link to remove malware" type messages. It also downloaded a file called "download"....I didn't find the file type. At the same time, avast! flagged it as containing malware. I immediately deleted the file and scanned my device with several antivirus scanners, which all came back clean.

Is there any chance there is anything nasty lingering on my phone? I didn't click the downloaded file, deleted immediately and my virus scans came back clean. I also don't allow installation from unknown sources.

Finally, can anyone recommend me a comprehensive antivirus program?

Comment: Unfortunately, Android antivirus solutions aren't very effective because of Android's sandbox.

Comment: I believe your device is safe. The ads is a scare-tactic to make you *install* the malware, and fortunately you mitigated this (also, thanks to Avast). App recommendation is unfortunately off-topic, though.